# Cm 12.1 Update - Bricked Phone

Tags: cyanogenmod

Well guys I seem to have bricked my phone. I updated my Nexus 4 from 12 to 12.1 and update went good but gapps failed as it constantly crashed on upstart. So I tried to update gapps with no success.

So I backed up my rom via ClockworkMod Recovery v6.0.4.7 and wipe data/factory reset. But I got an error, E: unknown volume for path [/sd-ext] and phone wont boot. Well I thought I better restore and see what I can do from there but I was not able to MD5 missmatch. So I figured I'm going to sideload an older version of CM and take it from there but I'm not able to because of google new security settings which are enabled.

So I try to bypass this as instructed from this tutorial "http://www.addictive...-adb-commands/" but none of these methods work.

When I try to clear dalvik cache log says
rm: can't remove 'data/dalvik-cache': No such file or directory
rm: can't remove 'cache/dalvik-cache': No such file or directory
rm: can't remove 'sd-ext/dalvik-cache': No such file or directory

Whats going on everything worked just fine until I updated to CM12.1 via built in updated system, I just don't understand why wipe/factory reset does not work.

I'm really out of ideas and would apprciate any advice.

Best Regards

Comment: I tried to fastboot a new rom but I just got "waiting for device" and nothing else happens

Comment: You did install a nightly so it us possible you will brick your phone :-) try to reflash cm12 from recovery mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I was forced to use adb sideload to reflash my phone. If this happens to anybody else, follow these steps to fix the issue:

- Install **ADB** on your computer, tutorials are easy to find, just Google.
- Boot to **Recovery** and navigate to **adb sideload**.
- Now set **adb sideload** on your phone and from you computer type

  `adb sideload` *`rom_image.zip`*   where *rom_image.zip* should be your ROM's file name.

This should reflash your phone.

Comment: `tutorials are easy to find, just Google.`  -- Could you please cite the source that worked for you? It could prove to be very useful for someone bothered by the mess of finding the right tool.

Comment: I did not use any tutorial for this because I know how to sideload but I google and found a tutorial if anybody needs one.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317986